# What can happen if I do not pay $735 for my negative balance to PayPal?

Tags: india, paypal, balance

I have a negative balance of -$735 on my PayPal account.

What can happen if I do not pay $735 for my negative balance to PayPal?

Please suggest me that PayPal can take any legal action to me.

I am from India.

Comment: Related: ["What legal action can Paypal take against me if I don't pay them and I have a negative balance?"](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/54471/10997) and ["Paypal Chargeback"](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/52288/10997)

Answer (score 4):

Exactly the same things will happen that would happen if you refused to pay anyone else you owe money to. They take you to court, you lose, you pay not only what you owe but the costs for their lawyers and any penalty the court adds. Why would you expect anything else?